# Vertioces treated differently after subdivide

Tags: subdivision-surface

I made this cube after which I subdivided the top layer with the Right Click-subdivide command. After that I again subdivided the front face, however I did it differently. This time I did not subdivide the whole selected surface, instead I selected only the left, right and bottom edges and subdivided those.

My problem is now I want to shrink the cube in the middle section. When I select the vertices however, the top ones are treated as surfaces except for the ones that are not highlighted. My guess is it's because I subdivided edges into vertices instead of surfaces into sub-surfaces. How can I fix this so that the front face and the unselected top subdivisions are treated like the other ones?

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. Have you tried deleting the faces that aren't working properly and inserting new ones? You could also use the dissolve faces if it's a problem with geometry. Using un-subdivide might also work.

Comment: Try selecting them in wireframe mode. However look at the vertical corners there are vertices that don't belong there. You can continue with this, but I strongly recommend you use loop cuts, instead of subdividing connected portions of your mesh.

Comment: @dogking57 I started fixing it by deleting the vertices. Turns out that somehow I ended up having 3 of them on top of each other on the top closest edge and bottom closest. I would like to know why this odd behavior though

Comment: I would assume it was because you only subdivided 3 edges which may have produced an odd result. If you want to divide your mesh, but don't want too many faces, I would recommend using ctrl + r for loop cuts like Frederik Steinmetz said.